# Can I load .phtml files using PHP builtin server?

Tags: php, php-builtin-server

With the default config, PHP's built-in server treats .phtml files as static resources. Is there any way to make it process them as regular .php scripts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a router script you should be able to check for phtml and then just include the file.

```
<?php
if (preg_match('/\.(?:php|phtml)$/', $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])) {
    require('./' . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
    return;
}
return false;
```

http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php#example-405

Comment: This was so obvious! I had already figured out using a router to check for .phtml, but got stuck on how to tell the interpreter to process the file. I am a little embarrassed I didn't realize right away a simple include would do. Thanks for getting me out of it :-)

Comment: At first I was in the same trap, but then suddenly it dawned on me that this is a php file, so I can do everything.